How to prevent simultaneous logins with the same user credentials in k6 for realistic web UI testing?
I'm building a web UI test in k6, where I have a list of users and passwords stored in a SharedArray. Each virtual user (VU) logs in with one of these credentials and performs an ordering process. However, when I run the test with 20 VUs, some VUs end up logging in at the same time with the same credentials. This results in overlapping orders for the same account, which makes the test unrealistic.
I've already tried the solution suggested here on the Grafana community forums(https://community.grafana.com/t/unique-login-for-each-virtual-user/99596), but it didn’t resolve the issue for me. The locking mechanism didn't work as expected to prevent VUs from picking the same user credentials simultaneously.
Ideally, each VU should select a unique user from the list, or at the very least, avoid using the same credentials at the same time.
How can I prevent multiple VUs from logging in simultaneously with the same user credentials in k6? A solution with example code would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!
